# Prove there exist a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av=v$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove that if $A^t=A^{-1}$, $\det(A)>0$ for a matrix $A_{3\times3}$ then exist a vector $v$ non-zero such that $Av=v$.

I tried taking a general matrix A,

$
\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
  a_{31}& a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{array} \right) $

but I don't get anything, and I tried using the definition of eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenvector $v$, $\{v \in V \mid Av=\lambda v\}$, and I did not get anything important, so, any hint is very valuable, thanks!

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to showing that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Notice that $1$ is a singular value of $A$ since $A^TA=I$ where $I$ is the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v\in\mathbb R^3$, then\begin{align}\lVert Av\rVert^2&=\langle Av,Av\rangle\\&=\langle v,A^tAv\rangle\\&=\langle v,v\rangle\text{ (since $A^t=A^{-1}$)}\\&=\lVert v\rVert^2\end{align}and therefore $\lVert Av\rVert=\lVert v\rVert$. On the other hand, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a cubic polynomial and therefore it has a real root $\lambda$. So, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$; let $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector. We have\begin{align}\lVert v\rVert&=\lVert Av\rVert\\&=\lVert\lambda v\rVert\\&=\lvert\lambda\rvert.\lVert v\rVert\end{align}and therefore $\lambda=\pm1$. If $\lambda=1$, we're done. If $\lambda=-1$, let $W=v^\perp=\{w\in\mathbb R^3\,|\,\langle v,w\rangle=0\}$. Then $A.W\subset W$. The determinant of $A|_W$ must be negative, since $0<\det(A)=(-1)\times\det(A|_W)$. But a $2\times2$ matrix with negative determinant always has eigenvalues (the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is greater than $0$). Therefore one of the eigenvalue of $A|_W$ is positive and the other one is negative. Since we found a positive eigenvalue, and since we have already proved that the only positive eigenvalue that $A$ can have is $1$, we're done.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you!

Comment: @José Carlos Santos On the other hand, the characteristic polynomial of A is a cubic polynomial and therefore it has a real root λ. Why is that true?

Comment: @heiverjust Are you asking me why every cubic polynomial (with real coefficients) has a real root?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Yes

Comment: @heiverjust You will find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160553/is-it-true-that-a-3rd-order-polynomial-must-have-at-least-one-real-root).

Answer (score 1):

If $A^tA=I$, $\det(A)>0$ for a  matrix $A_{3\times3}$  then obviously $A$ is   some rotation matrix.

Such matrix has many representations, one of them  is    [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation).

$A=I+\sin\theta K(v)+(1-\cos\theta) K^2(v)$

where $K(v)$ is skew-symmetric matrix linked with some vector $v$.

Image for this matrix is orthogonal to $v$, consequently by direct calculations we have from the formula $Av=v$.

Comment: Matrix $K$ is defined as $[ v \times i \ \ v \times j \ \ v \times k ]$ what implies obviously $Kv=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Such matrices are called *orthogonal*.

It is well known that orthogonal matrices act as isometries of Euclidean space,  such as rotations, reflections or rotoreflections.

Read about them [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).

In fact,  we have a rotation,  since $\operatorname{det}A\gt0$. (We have an element of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$, the *special orthogonal group*.)  The claim follows.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're quite welcome