# Show that a matrix $A\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ always has at least one real eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would one go about doing this?

I tried creating a general matrix in the following way:

$$ A =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now from here, my reasoning was to just try and find a general expression for the characteristic polynomial which is $det(A-\lambda I)$ but that turned out to be a dead end (at least for me) because I was not able to factor anything out and thus make it an eigenvalue that works regardless of the numbers in the matrix.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: a cubic polynomial [always](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160553/is-it-true-that-a-3rd-order-polynomial-must-have-at-least-one-real-root) has a real root

Comment: Well, a *real* cubic polynomial. :) Think about the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Would it be enough to just state that complex solutions always appear in pairs and therefore one of the three solutions that we know are going to exist is actually real?

Comment: @TedShifrin The intermediate value theorem seems like it could be helpful here. I'm assuming that you are thinking of our characteristic polynomial for this matrix as just a polynomial function that has to be continuous on its whole domain. I still however do not see how this means that it has to have a real root. I really does not seem to me like it has to cross the x-axis necessarily.

Comment: @LukaDuranovic:  I think so

Comment: You can always find a value of $x$ for which a real cubic polynomial in $x$ is positive; ditto for the value of the cubic being negative. Recall, for instance, what it means for $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for your answer. After doing some more research I think that you are right on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(t) = \det (tI -A) = t^3 \det(I - {1 \over t} A)$.

Note that $\phi$ is a polynomial in $t$ and so is continuous.

Hence $\lim_{t \to -\infty} \phi(t)= -\infty$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \phi(t)= \infty$
and so $\phi$ must take the value $0$ somewhere.

**Alternatively**:

Note that $\phi$ has 3 roots.

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $\phi(\overline{z}) = \overline{\phi(z)}$, hence if $z$ is a root then $\overline{z}$ is also a root. In particular, if there is a non real root, then its conjugate is also another root. Hence the number of non real roots is even, and hence we can have either $0$ or $2$ non real roots. And so this
means we have $1$ or $3$ real roots.

Comment: Include the observation that $\phi$, being a polynomial, is continuous.